# Ruby's Mechanize balks when selecting a radio button (maybe because its name is capitalized) but Perl's WWW::Mechanize works fine

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to submit a form with Ruby's Mechanize gem. This form has a set of radio buttons named "KeywordType". The individual buttons are named something like rdoAny, rdoAll and rdoPhrase. With Perl's WWW:Mechanize it works just fine:

```
my $result = $agent->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields => {
        txtKeywords => 'foo bar baz',
        lstLocationCode => '2100',
        lstONETMajorGroup => '0',
        KeywordType => 'rdoAny'
    },
    button => 'btnSearch'
);
```

but Ruby balks when I do this:

```
result = page.form_with(:id => 'frmSearch') do |field|
    field.txtKeywords = 'foo bar baz'
    field.lstLocationCode = '2100'
    field.lstONETMajorGroup = '0'
    field.KeywordType = 'rdoAny'
end.submit
```

This throws the error

```
"undefined method `KeywordType=' for #<Mechanize::Form:0x00000001c896e0> (NoMethodError)".
```

I've tried leaving out the KeywordType field, but then I just get sent back to the same page with no obvious error message. I've also tried doing things like field.radiobuttons.second.check and field.radiobuttons_with(:name => "KeywordType") to no avail.

And on a side note, is whatever's going on because Ruby sees a capitalized radiobutton name and thinks it's a constant?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of calling your form `field`, how about: `form`

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
field['KeywordType'] = 'rdoAny'
```

Edit: Oh, and I think you missed a part here:

```
result = page.form_with(:id => 'frmSearch') do |field|
```

should be (I think):

```
result = page.form_with(:id => 'frmSearch').fields.each do |field|
```

Comment: This didn't work, but thanks for giving it a shot. I appear to have other troubles; the dropdowns lstLocationCode and lstONETMajorGroup are not being populated, and that might in fact be where the real problem is happening.

Comment: Oops, my bad. After the update described below the field[''] syntax is now working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Gaah. The outdated version gremlin strikes again. "gem update mechanize" is now at least showing me the values for the two dropdowns.